# How to set the DestroyAPIView method not real delete my instance?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model, like bellow:

```
class BModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    status = models.CharField(default="is_active")  # if delete:  deleted
    a = models.ForeignKey(AModel)

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        pass  # there I want to set the BModel's status to `deleted`
```

Serializer:

```
class BModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

Its Views is bellow:

```
class BModelListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BModelSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = BModel.objects.all()

class BModelDestroyAPIView(DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = BModelSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = BModel.objects.all()
```

My requirement is when use Django-Rest-Framework delete my BModel, I want to set the BModel's status field to `deleted`, not real delete the instance. How to access it?

when I tried to write a delete method to my Model, there comes the default delete method:

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
```

I have some questions about this:
Is this is for the BModel's instance？
Whether should through the delete method to access my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DestroyAPIView` has a `perform_destroy` method. You can override that and add your logic of deletion. For eg:

```
class BModelDestroyAPIView(DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = BModelSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = BModel.objects.all()

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.delete_flag = True
        instance.save()
```

The `delete` method of `BModel` will override the default delete method. Which will also affect the Django Admin. You can also add a custom delete method to Manager of that Model. [Refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/)